# Is a site's meta site the correct place to post a "meta" post for the site's meta site?

Tags: discussion, meta, off-topic, per-site-meta

I realise that is a complicated title. Permit me to elaborate via an example. If I was having a problem (say I found a bug) with for instance the [meta page for Skeptics.SE](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com). Would that question be best posted on said page or would it be better to post it elsewhere on the stackexchange site e.g. on this page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Site meta is a correct place for posts about site meta. To use an algorithmic/mathematical term, *meta* is [idempotent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1077412/): meta.meta is the same as meta. For example, a design flaw of meta.skeptics site should be reported on meta.skeptics.

All meta sites have a *meta* tag for this purpose: e.g., [meta tag on meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meta). It has not been used on [meta.skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta) yet; you can be the first!

Software bugs and feature requests that affect all Stack Exchange sites can be posted at either place: on site meta, or here on Meta.SE.

Comment: Is that why there is also no meta meta so to speak?

Comment: [Also because it would not stop there](http://www.xkcd.com/1447/).

Comment: Indeed! I was worried by the possibility on a never ending series - that would just be too meta!

Answer (score 2):

When the split between Meta.SO and Meta.SE occurred, some of us were unsure about where we should post. The moderators made it quite clear that for all SE sites, the users of any given site do not have to worry about the existence of Meta.SE. A user who runs into a problem on a given site can post their question to that site's Meta.

There's no exception for issues that arise from a site's Meta: these issues can be posted on the Meta for that site.